# C# DateTime.TryParseExact not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, tryparse

I hate to ask dumb questions but I've been through the MSDN article a couple times and trying stuff for an hour but no matter what I try I can't get this format to work. Here's what I'm trying to parse:

> Thu, Jun 22

With

```
bool parsed = DateTime.TryParseExact("Thu, Jun 22", @"ddd, MMM dd", CultureInfo.Invariant, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateAndTime);
```

Using the format:

```
ddd, MMM dd
```

Removing the ddd, works so I'm pretty certain there's something with the first part, but I'm not sure what. I've tried using ' ' around the comma and escaping it with backslash, with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since "Thu Jun 22" doesn't contain a year, the system will automatically infer the current year, so it will be treated as Thu Jun 22 2016.

Unfortunately, June 22, 2016 is not a Thursday, but actually a Friday.  So you should get a FormatException with that value.

Try adding a year or removing the weekday.